# Form using javascript make field required?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form that uses a javascript file `items.js` to add new items. So each time `form.php` is used and the 'add items' buttons is clicked then the new row of fields show to add details.

So for example some of the code is the following to add field item name.

```
newCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
newCell.innerHTML = '<input class="item_text_area item_name" type="text" name="0_item_' + new_item + '" id="0_item_' + new_items + '" size="20" maxlength="250" />';
```

How can I edit this `.js` file to make the Item name field required?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to add some sort of alert or just want to indicate the user that it is a required field?

Comment: For the rest of the form that isn't using the items.js I can just add class="blah required" and it will stop the form being submitted while letting the user know that the certain field is required. I would like the .js portion of the form to act the same.

Answer (score 2):

Per Jeevan: As you cannot be sure how many items the user submits, I would choose for an approach where all new items have unique class, say `dynamicAddedItems`.

As Jeevan already said, you can add the following to the form tag to prevent it from submitting if it returns `false`.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();"></form>
```

With javascript:

```
function validate(){
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName( 'dynamicAddedItems' );
  var allgood = true;

  //Loop through all elements with this class
  for( var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
    if( !elems[i].value || !elems[i].value.length ) {
      elems[i].className += " error";
      allgood = false;
    } else {
      elems[i].className = "item_text_area item_name dynamicAddedItems";
    }
  }

  //If any element did not meet the requirements, prevent it from being submitted and display an alert
  if( !allgood ) {
    alert( "Please fill in all the required fields." );
    return false;
  }

  //Otherwise submit the form
  return true;
}
```

This script will add the error class if a field is empty and prevent the form from being submitted. It's up to you how you want to display a field with such a class.

Comment: @axon111 Please use the comment section to suggest improvements (as soon as you have the privilege to add comments). The break statement you added would prevent all wrong fields from being highlighted, which was not the way the code should work.

Answer (score -2):

You can use jquery for this. Add a class, in this case 'requiredAttr' to the required fields and then validate on form submit.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
  First Name*: <input class="requiredAttr" type="text" /><br/>
  Last Name: <input type="text" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

function validate(){
$(".requiredAttr").each(function(){
    if($(this).val().length < 1){
        alert("please fill in all the required fields.");
        $(this).focus();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
});
return false;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle. It also brings the focus on the first un-filled field after the validation alert:

http://jsfiddle.net/YG6mk/2/

Comment: -1 If the user doesn't state that they use jQuery, an answer using 'raw' javascript is required. It would be nice if you put all the relevant code in your answer too, as the jsfiddle will not be available until eternity.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Firstly the OP HASN'T mentioned that he isn't using jquery. Secondly, if there is a better/easier/faster/etc. way of doing something it is always a good thing to point it out. That is why we are all here, to help. About the jsfiddle,  it is always better to use a working example. This is not supposed to be here forever. If you think jsfiddle won't be around till eternity, what makes you think SO will?

Comment: Hover over the javascript tag.

Comment: @Sumurai8 javascript file, a .js file. Man, I wonder what extension jquery files use.

Comment: It doesn't matter if SO will be available until eternity. Without jsfiddle, your answer simply has no value for anyone else that has the same question. It is likely, that jsfiddle will eventually clean up all unused jsfiddles, which means your answer will be mostly gone. Jsfiddle should be an addition.

Comment: There dude. Btw jquery == javascript. I hope you do agree that jquey is easier to use. If you do then like I said, we are all here to help.

Comment: "JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language commonly used for client-side scripting. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript). Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected." That is what the javascript tag says. jQuery is easy. True. That doesn't mean it is needed or a good idea to add a dependancy for a library, just to validate a form. You don't need to build a foundation for a skyscraper if you are building a tree house.

Comment: So, then I suppose the OP has a website with one page with one form on it. I stand corrected.